# SQL Server - Function call in WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I've a question regarding making a function call in WHERE condition of a SELECT statement in my stored procedure. Here is my sample query that mimics my original. I've 3 million records in the production database for primary table CDP. My concern is if there would be any performance impact of using the function testFunction(@UserId) in my WHERE clause.

```
SELECT C.AwardId, C.ProgramName, Count(ClientId) as Intakes FROM CDP C 
     LEFT JOIN UserRoleEntity URE ON C.AwardId = URE.EntityId 
     LEFT JOIN UserRole UR ON URE.UserRoleId = UR.Id AND UR.CDPUserId = @UserId
WHERE (1=1) -- here I've other filtering criteria for the results
 AND (   testFunction(@UserId) = 0
      OR (UR.ID IS NOT NULL AND UR.CDPUserId = @UserId))
GROUP BY C.AwardId, C.ProgramName
```

My question is - Does the function get called for EVERY record in the result set? Since there are 3 million records in CDP table, does the function get called 3 million times and impact the performace?

My assumption is that - the function in WHERE clause would be called ONLY ONCE on the final result set, to filter the results.

Will it be ONCE or 3 million times is my question. BTW - my function contains a simple select statement, with inner joins to 2 tables, and returns a numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you can do this. Assign the `function` result to a `variable` and use it in `where` clause

```
declare @check int,
select @check = dbo.testFunction(@UserId)

SELECT C.AwardId, C.ProgramName, Count(ClientId) as Intakes FROM CDP C 
     LEFT JOIN UserRoleEntity URE ON C.AwardId = URE.EntityId 
     LEFT JOIN UserRole UR ON URE.UserRoleId = UR.Id AND UR.CDPUserId = @UserId
WHERE (1=1) -- here I've other filtering criteria for the results
 AND (   @check = 0
      OR (UR.ID IS NOT NULL AND UR.CDPUserId = @UserId))
GROUP BY C.AwardId, C.ProgramName
```

Comment: Good workaround. Yet, I would first determine if you need it by looking at the query plan.

Comment: Awesome! That totally works.. I don't know why I haven't thought about it. Thank you so much!!!